# Securely Store (and Retrieve) UserName In Powershell Scripts

Tags: .net, powershell

we need to encrypt and store our username as well. How can we do that ?

Here is my script:

```
$username = 'DOMAIN\user'

$encryptedPassword = '01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb010.........'
$encryptedPassword = $encryptedPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString
$pointer = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode($encryptedPassword)
$decryptedPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($pointer)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeCoTaskMemUnicode($pointer)

$encryptedPassword = $encryptedPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $encryptedPassword

# Do something
```

cheers,

Comment: You may take a look at the module [Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.secretmanagement/?view=ps-modules)

Comment: If you start with a *plain text* user name (and presumably eventually also convert it back to plain text), your design will never get secure [A **SecureString** object should never be constructed from a **String**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-6.0#securestring-operations). The most you can do is [hide your string](https://github.com/iRon7/HiddenString) aka [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Comment: Overall, SecureString is more secure than String because it limits the exposure of sensitive string data. However, those strings may still be exposed to any process or operation that has access to raw memory, such as a malicious process running on the host computer, a process dump, or a user-viewable swap file. Instead of using SecureString to protect passwords, the recommended alternative is to **use an opaque handle to credentials that are stored outside of the process**. Meaning: don't let your script do the authorization but authenticate/authorize the account that runs the script.

Comment: What/who are you protecting against? Who's not supposed to see the user names, and why?